# What is the role of a shofet (as in the book of Shoftim)?

Tags: beit-din-court, shoftim--book-of

In the book of Shoftim (Judges) we are introduced to a the role of a shofet ("judge"). At first glance, it's a very vague role.

Hashem uses judges to prevent the Jews from sinning. But not much else is explained.

Is a Shofet similar to a prophet, a gadol hador, or is it to be taken literally as a "Judge" like an av bet din?

Answer (score -2):

"Shoftim" translates roughly as "generals"

Comment: In Israel, the word "Shofet" is used to refer to a "dayan" in a secular court.

Comment: [Edit]ing in any source or evidence for this answer will greatly improve its quality!